# cannot reload .profile from script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ksh

I am trying to reload `.profile` from the below script, but that doesn't work at all.

```
#!/bin/ksh
sed -i '/export rel=Rel1510_Linux/c\export rel=Rel1602_MX' ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

When I run this script, it just performs the `sed` operation but reload doesn't happen. A sample run is below:

```
rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1510_Linux> ./switchTo1602.ksh
rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1510_Linux>
```

And thus, I have to run `source` from the terminal directly to reload the profile.

```
rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1510_Linux> source ~/.profile
rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1602_MX>
```

What am I missing here ? Please help.

Comment: what do you mean *reload doesn't happen*? are you calling this script from `~/.profile` mid-`source`?

Comment: When you run the first script, it's launching a sub-shell, running the script, and in that sub-shell it's sourcing the profile, then the script ends, and so does the sub-shell, returning you to your previous shell in which none of the environment has changed.  It might work if you reconfigure this as an alias, not a script, so it runs in your current shell when executed.

Answer (score 0):

rohit,

After the source do `bash` command on script will fix this.

`bash` command will reload the env variables.

Comment: but that takes the shell into bash. And the shell changes like this:
`rk248c:/opt/app/capm/users/rk248c/Rel1602_MX>./switchTo1510.ksh`

`[rk248c@zld01700 Rel1510_Linux]$`

How can I keep the previous shell ?

Comment: then use eval instead of source

Comment: that didn't work :(